# When i am running a code why is it showing IndexError: list index out of range?

Tags: python-3.x

I am just practicing Python from Hackerrank trying different methods to solve problems. But i am facing some errors.

I am trying to compare two numbers in a list successively.

```
def breakingRecords(scores):

    length_score=len(scores)
    c=0
    z=0


    for i in range(length_score):

         q=scores[i + 1]


         if (scores[i]<q):
             c+=1
         elif scores[i]>q:
             z+=1
         else:
             z=0 
    return [c,z]     

q=scores[i + 1]
```

IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the index variable of your range (`i`) goes from 0 to `n-1` (then number of elements in the list minus 1) an in your loop you have `q=scores[i + 1]` which, when `i` reaches the last element, `i + 1` will be the size of the list which is not a valid index.

So if your list has five (`5`) elements with valid indexes from `0 to 4`, `i` will go from `0` to `4` but when `i = 4`, `4 + 1 = 5` which does not exist, hence the error.

A fix to your code will be:

```
def breakingRecords(scores):
    length_score = len(scores) - 1
    c = 0
    z = 0

    for i in range(length_score):
        q = scores[i + 1]

        if scores[i] < q:
            c += 1
        elif scores[i] > q:
            z += 1
        else:
            z = 0

    return [c, z]
```

Comment: I concede that this is the more correct answer, I failed to read the question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```py
     q=scores[i + 1]
```

with:

```py
     q=scores[i]
```

The loop going through `range(length_score)` will go through all the integers between `0` and `length_score-1` (incl)
so by referring to `i+1` you will hit `scores[len(scores)]` as a last element - which will return index out of range exception.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your

> q = scores[i + 1]

to

> q = scores[i]

Run the example below and it should make sense to you.

```
my_array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for i in range(len(my_array)):
    print(f"index = {i} ; value={my_array[i]}")
```

yields;

```
index = 0 ; value=a
index = 1 ; value=b
index = 2 ; value=c
index = 3 ; value=d
index = 4 ; value=e
```

Comment: i want to compare numbers consecutively in a list. For example: [1,2,3,4,5], i want to compare  1 and 2 then 2 and 3 then 3 and 4

Comment: Then, in actuality, Omari's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to compare numbers consecutively in a list. For example: [1,2,3,4,5], i want to compare 1 and 2 then 2 and 3 then 3 and 4

`zip()` is your friend:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for first, second in zip(numbers, numbers[1:]):
    print("{} - {}".format(first, second)
```